# Facebook Like using meta og:image ignored and shows my website logo instead

Tags: facebook

Its really strange because the FB "Share" is using my logo image instead of the one that I assigned in the

meta property="og:image:url" content="http://mywebsite.com/images/whatever.png"

I try my link to the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object and the image shows correct. This happen only in the "Share" frame, the "Recommend" button has no problem and it shows the right image.

Any body have experienced on this? I am using more than h200px x w200px image.

Note: http://mywebsite.com/images/whatever.png is not the real path.

I think FB is trying to find other images at the top of the page instead of using the meta imgae they provide.

Please help guys.

Comment: Facebook changed their buttons recently. I think og:type is also important. You get a different look with different og:type. The default og:type is now website. I want to expirement with different og:type to get the best looking share. Also Facebook wants bigger images, it always seems to honor og:image an issue I found with Pinterest is some images can't be pinned due to size or having a + in the file name. Try renaming the file and path to not have any non-alphanumeric characters. Try also resizing the image. Bigger is better now in social media.

Answer (score 0):

Try This for sharing user defined title,description and image from facebook

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]={your page title}&p[summary]={your description}|&p[url]={Url that you want share}&p[images][0]={image url}
```